# Saving lists to models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm building a tracker where users save their response to the same question every day. Is there a way to track individual responses as a **list** through models.py?

I don't see a model field for lists, so I'm saving the list of responses through views.py at the moment.

```
mylist = []
global length

@login_required
def add(request):
respond = Response.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_option = (request.POST['rating'])
    length = len(mylist)
    if selected_option == 'option1':
        mylist.append(1)
        print(respond.score)
    elif selected_option == 'option2':
        mylist.append(2)
        print(respond.score)
    elif selected_option == 'option3':
        mylist.append(3)
        print(respond.score)
    elif selected_option == 'option4':
        mylist.append(4)
        print(respond.score)
    elif selected_option == 'option5':
        mylist.append(5)
        print(respond.score)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(400, 'Invalid form')

    for votes in respond:
        votes.save()

    return redirect(add)

context = {
    'respond' : respond,
    'mylist' : mylist
}
return render(request, 'rating/add.html', context)

def graph(request):
x_data = list(range(0,len(mylist)))
y_data = list(mylist)
return render(request, "rating/home.html", context={'plot_div': plot_div, 'mylist' : mylist})
```

This accomplishes my need to save responses to a list so that I can send them over to a plot. The issue is that it doesn't save as part of the model and as such is not linked directly to any specific user (all user results are grouped together).

I'm using this for my models file right now but unsure how to link and save the poll results to it:

```
class Response(models.Model):
responder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    return self.score
```

How should I be setting up my model to be able to save a list of responses (numerical values) that can be plotted?

Comment: Most databases don't have good support for lists/arrays. Probably you should use a `JsonField`, or define a model that with a `ForeignKey` makes a collection of items.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using JSONField

Answer (score 0):

aren't you using a ManyToMany field, to store the user's responses for each 'question' ?

Comment: I think you're right, thanks! I'm still struggling with how to save any of the responses to the database